# SCSS: Send Attribute and Value to Function

Tags: function, sass, mixins

Note:

I'm new to web development and object oriented programming. I am brand new to SCSS and haven't yet grasped a solid understanding of the syntax. I have a basic understanding of how to use [functions in SCSS](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions).

Let me start off by defining the result I want to achieve.

_body.scss

```
body {

   background-color: red;

}
```

Now I know if I wanted to obtain this result in Javascript I could:

Option 1: write a string of HTML code and replace the existing html tag.

Not going to code this, as this is a messy way of writing Javascript, but essentially using document.write() method.

Option 2: use the "setAttribute()" method

```
// assuming <head> and <body> are the only tags within <html>

var bodyTag = document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild;

bodyTag.setAttribute( "bgcolor", "red" );
```

I know there are additional ways to do this in Javascript, but for this example, I will focus on these two.

So I want to create a SCSS function that can return both the attribute and the value.

_body.scss ( Pseudocode string example )

```
@function makeAttribute( $attribute, $value )

{

   @return $attribute + ":" + $value + ";";

}

body {

   makeAttribute( background-color, red );

}
```

I have yet to find a built in function that addresses this ( similar to the "setAttribute()" method in Javascript ), or the string example above.

I know that functions can take: number, string, bool, color, list, map or null; but what I don't know is if an attribute fits into any of these value types ( for instance: string ).

I feel as if the article: [Bringing Configuration Objects To Sass](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/05/05/bringing-configuration-objects-to-sass/) may be explaining what I am trying to do, but I'm having difficulty understanding this article ( so it may not be an explanation to a solution ).

My end goal is to create a function that would write the following css. I did not mention the browser support previously as it adds another layer of complexity that may or may not be easily explained.

```
body {

   background-color: red;

   -o-background-color: red;

   -ms-background-color: red;

   -moz-background-color: red;

   -webkit-background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: You are confusing CSS, Javascript and HTML - they are very different languages, and 'setAttribute' functions wouldn't make a lot of sense in CSS, as `background: red;` _is essentially setAttribute_. Don't try to translate your CSS from Javascript or even the other way around - things will get confusing fast.

Comment: Yes I was just providing examples of Javascript and HTML. I was in no way suggesting to take code from one language and put it in another. I'm trying to find out if SASS / SCSS has either build in methods / functions or a way to write a custom function to produce the desired output.

Comment: Well, here's a good starting article: http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions - and I upvoted the answer below as it explains the premise as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if this have to be a function, i found it more logic use a mixin instead:

```
// Option 1

@mixin makeRule($value: red, $property: background-color) {
  #{$property}: $value;
}

// Option 2:

@mixin makeRuleWithPrefixes($value: red, $property: background-color) {
  #{-ms- + $property}: $value;
  #{-o- + $property}: $value;
  #{-moz- + $property}: $value;
  #{-webkit- + $property}: $value;
  #{$property}: $value;
}


/////////

body {
  @include makeRule;
}

article {
  @include makeRule(black);
}

p {
  @include makeRule(2px solid blue, border)
}


span {
  @include makeRuleWithPrefixes;
}
```

i changed the name, because is no right say - makeAttribute, when you are creating a cssRule ( selector + property name + property value ), well this is up to you ;)

ok the first,**[you need interpolation to use a variable as a property name](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)**.
The value is the first argument, so now **you can use the default property**, and just pass different values ( like the article :) )

**or you can now set all the properties you want it**, just pass the property as the second value ( like p )

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}

article {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

span {
  -ms-background-color: red;
  -o-background-color: red;
  -moz-background-color: red;
  -webkit-background-color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I made the option two, because you ask it but i warn you, this is not a good approach. You could use a build tool ( webpack, gulp, grunt.. whatever )  than use a autoprefixer package that do this prefix automatically, this way is a pain because you have to be updating the @mixin eventually.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Just hadn't discovered the #{ } syntax yet. Documentation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Thanks Héctor León.

Comment: glad to help you, keep coding ;)